# Convert cognitoUser.authenticateUser callback to observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, amazon-cognito

I'm building an angular app using AWS Cognito Javascript SDK for authentication.

I have a service on which I have a `login` method:

```
login(username: string, password: string): void {
  const authData = {
    Username: username,
    Password: password
  };
  const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authData);
  const userData = {
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool
  };
  this.cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  const self = this;
  this.cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: self.onSuccess.bind(self),
    onFailure: self.onFailure.bind(self),
    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
      self.newPasswordRequired.next(true);
      self.authIsLoading.next(false);
    }
  });
}
```

Now, instead of using callbacks directly on the service, I would like to return an observable from `login` method, to which I may subscribe and get the result of authentication: success, failure or new password required.

I took a look the Observable [bindCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) and [bindNodeCallback](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) methods and also on this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925040/use-observable-for-aws-cognito-callback), but couldn't figure out how to do this.

How may this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can return new Observable and fire the observers with next() and error():

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<{ type: string, result: any }>{
  const authData = {
    Username: username,
    Password: password
  };
  const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authData);
  const userData = {
    Username: username,
    Pool: userPool
  };
  this.cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  return new Observable<{ type: string, result: any}>(obs => {
    this.cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result: any) => {
        obs.next({ type: 'success', result: result });
        obs.complete();
      },
      onFailure: (error: any) => obs.error(error),
      newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, requiredAttributes) => {
        obs.next({ type: 'newPasswordRequired', result: [userAttributes, requiredAttributes] });
        obs.complete();
      }
    });
  });
}
```